# ¿Compilar código en c con gcc, sin que se abra la consola al ejecutar?

Tags: gcc, winapi

Estoy creando una aplicación gráfica en C, utilizando la api de windows Win32 API, lo compilo de forma normal

```
gcc -o aplicacion main.c
```

Al momento de ejecutar la aplicación, primero se abre una terminal y lo que quiero es que se abra directamente la aplicación, sin que este abierta una ventana del cmd.

[image: Así es como se ejecuta la aplicación]

Yo solo quiero que aparezca la pura ventana, sin el cmd.

Comment: aquí hay un par de pistas https://stackoverflow.com/q/4441551/1423096